# Can't copy field to another: 'Empty value for Objectid = 0'

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I tried to copy a field with dates that had type 'TEXT' to a new column of type 'DATE' because it is not possible to change the initial type of the original field.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Deuv.shp','DC_DATE','DC_DATE1')
```

The initial field has all rows with data but it gives this error:

> 'Empty value for Objectid = 0'

And it can't copy anything to the other field.

Comment: select the ones where the date field isn't empty for a start then read up on calculating dates from strings (eg https://community.esri.com/thread/22042), I would use a python parser instead of omitting the parser and defaulting to VBscript, dates are a little bit special so to help much more we would need to know what storage type your feature class is (OBJECTID means geodatabase, it's 0 not o as OBJECTID is numeric, but enterprise, file and personal geodatabases have their own quirks).

Comment: @user10680652 I would rather use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`. Here you can convert your string data into date format.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table where the text field with the "dates" are visible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your text into a datetime format. So using the datetime.strptime method, you have to decipher what your text date looks like, and convert that into a datetime format.

Using the UpdateCursor, you can search for your string date, convert that into a datetime object, then update the new field with the correct date object.

Please see [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for more information on the DateTime python module.

For example:

```
import datetime

string_date = "23/11/18 12:30"

string_date_into_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

print string_date_into_datetime
```

Comment: tried turning 15/01/2015 with YYYY/MM/dd in arcpy and turned to 15/Jan/2015. How to turn it to as it was with 01 instead of Jan?

Comment: Use %m instead of %b